# Construction of any angle below 60°

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, geometric-construction

This is only applicable when θ is less than 60.
Let x be the length of one side of the angle on the x-axis (Or whatever axis)
The angle formed with the pt. O and a pt on a circle with radius = x*(60/θ) and a circle of radius x with centre at B, Will be θ.
[image]

---

So could anyone help me with how this is it true (if it is at all.) and is there anything like this?

Actually I accidentally came to the above-mentioned conclusion this when I was trying to draw 20° without a protractor.

Comment: It's close, but it gives $\arcsin \frac16 \approx 19.47^\circ$.  There are certain non-constructable angles—$20^\circ$ is one of them.  (Nonconstructible only with compass and straightedge, that is.)

Comment: The Wikipedia plot summary for [Nonagon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonagon) gives some interesting approximations for $40^\circ$.

Comment: It is not clear to me what you ask. It is always true. Where is the 1/6 coming from?

Comment: I didn't know if this was correct or not